# Account activation and deactivation - Laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a laravel project and I use laravelbrise for authentication, I created a function to deactivate and reactivate accounts, for deactivated accounts I would like to block the connection for certain users. Thank you for your help.

I tried to go to the App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController file to modify the login controller but it doesn't work